# Perforce wildcard problem in branch specification

Tags: version-control, branch, perforce

In a branch spec, I have the following view:

```
//depot/dev/t/a/g/... //depot/dev/t/r/g/...
-//depot/dev/t/a/g/p/o*/... //depot/dev/t/r/g/p/...
```

Perforce reports an "Incompatible wildcards" for the second rule there.

What I'd like to do is exclude all the directories beginning with "o".

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you need to have matching wildcards on both sides of each mapping.  Try:

```
//depot/dev/t/a/g/... //depot/dev/t/r/g/...
-//depot/dev/t/a/g/p/o*/... //depot/dev/t/r/g/p/o*/...
```

Answer (score 3):

While not a direct answer to the question (answered above), I was stumped on the same message and found this post while trying to search for a solution.

In my case, it was because when copy-pasting the workspace mapping from another file, the ellipsis character was placed instead of the Perforce "..." wildcard. To fix this, I deleted the ellipsis and replaced it by typing in three periods.

Comment: Note: This problem might occur when copying workspace mappings from a formatted resource like office documents etc.